# Code correct in IDE but gives error in CodeChef

Tags: java

i am trying to solve codechef question i am able to get the output in IDE and also with custom input, when i try to run with there inputs then it gives me the error

**link to question:**
https://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST

**Code:**

```
    /* package codechef; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Codechef
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int numberOne = input.nextInt();
        float numberTwo = input.nextFloat();
        float reduction = 0;
        float result = 0;
        DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".00");
        if(numberOne > 0 && numberOne <= 2000 & numberTwo >= 0 && numberTwo <= 2000){
        if(numberOne % 5 == 0){
            reduction = (float)numberOne+(0.50f);
            if(reduction <= numberTwo){
                result = numberTwo-reduction;

                System.out.println(df2.format(result));
            }
            if(reduction > numberTwo){
                System.out.println(df2.format(numberTwo));
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(df2.format(numberTwo));
        }
        }

    }

}
```

**Error:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException   at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)     at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)  at
>   Codechef.main(Main.java:14)

Comment: This is caused by `nextInt` and/or `nextFloat` not been able to meet the requirements based on the input.  You might need to use `nextLine` instead and test convert the `String`s to `int` and `double` manually

Comment: sorry but nextLine is also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple thing worked for me ....
i only surrounded the code by try and catch....

**final  working code...**

```
/* package codechef; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Codechef
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        try{
        int n, sum = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = s.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[i] = s.nextInt();
        }

        int largest=0;
        int element=0;


        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                element=a[i]%a[j];
                if(largest<element){
                    largest=element;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(largest);
    }
            catch(Exception e){

    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The "error" is caused by the input not been parsable as the required type (ie, `Scanner` can not either parse the input as `int` or `float`)

"A" solution would be to take the input and manually parse it.  You could use `nextLine` and run another `Scanner` over it, or split on a common delimiter, or you could simple use `next`, for example...

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Codechef {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String element = input.next(); // Next value up to the next space or new line...
        int numberOne = Integer.parseInt(element);
        element = input.next(); // Next value up to the next space or new line...
        float numberTwo = Float.parseFloat(element);
        float reduction = 0;
        float result = 0;
        DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".00");
        if (numberOne > 0 && numberOne <= 2000 & numberTwo >= 0 && numberTwo <= 2000) {
            if (numberOne % 5 == 0) {
                reduction = (float) numberOne + (0.50f);
                if (reduction <= numberTwo) {
                    result = numberTwo - reduction;

                    System.out.println(df2.format(result));
                }
                if (reduction > numberTwo) {
                    System.out.println(df2.format(numberTwo));
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(df2.format(numberTwo));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This assumes that the input is provided, generally, on a single line, but this method will allow you to deal with two seperate inputs.  But without know exactly what the inputs are, it's hard to provide a more precise solution

Answer (score 1):

You're not consuming the space between the input values.

Just read the first line using nextLine, and then split and parse the numbers accordingly

Comment: when i try to read the first Line using nextLine then it gives me error :::: because nextLine is used to read the string ..i guess

Comment: Yes. Test again in your IDE using one line of input like codechef shows, rather than actually entering two values

Comment: facing the same issue

Comment: It's possible codechef uses the args of the main method rather than standard input

Comment: i used to take the argument from command line as .... args[0] ... but it is invalid