# I am writing a code for CodeChef. but getting error TLE is it possible to optimize it more?

Tags: java, optimization

I am writing a code for CodeChef. but getting error TLE (2.10000) is it possible to optimize it more?

**Question Link:**
https://www.codechef.com/APRIL19B/problems/STRCH

**code:**

```
/* package codechef; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Codechef
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
         Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
         int  T = ss.nextInt();

             for(int k=0;k<T;k++){

                         int counter=0;
                         int N=ss.nextInt();
                         String S=ss.next();
                         char c=ss.next().charAt(0);
                         int sLengthOne=S.lastIndexOf(c);
                         int sLengthTwo=S.length();
                         if(S.length()==N){
                                 for (int i = 0; i <= sLengthOne; i++) {
                                    for (int j = 1; j <= sLengthTwo-i; j++) {
                                        if(S.substring(i,i+j).indexOf(c)!=-1){
                                            counter++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                         System.out.println(counter);
                         }
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: optimizing is what you have to do when it works, and you want to improve it. What you first need to do, is fixing it. Is there any particular reason why you are hiding Exceptions?

Comment: you are asking about try and catch right ? why i used ?

Comment: unless and until i use try and catch it is not allowing me to submit the code no idea why

Comment: No, I'm asking you why you allow your code to crash without you ever being able to notice that it crashed, let alone why

Comment: sorry but i did not got your point

Comment: Do you know what a try-catch block does?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566645/code-correct-in-ide-but-gives-error-in-codechef/55570834#55570834

Comment: i was facing the problem get through the link

Comment: so you don't know what try-catch does. I recommend reading up on it. It might explain how your catch block can help you understand/learn what is going wrong.
--> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

Comment: codechef not allow me to submit the code dear unless and until i surround it in try catch

Comment: ... I 'm not telling you not to use try catch, I'm telling you to actually use it in a decent way. We don't know what is going on, but if you check what goes on in your catch block, if you print a stacktrace, if you create a log, ... you might

Comment: i printed the stacktrace in catch ...it do not give error

Comment: the problem i am facing only is it is exceeding the given time limit of one second by them

Comment: the result is coming is correct but time required to execute the code is more than one second

Comment: You do understand we have no idea what your code is supposed to do, right?

Comment: thats why i have given the question link dear go through before answering

Comment: for you i willl remove try catch fine

Answer (score 1):

Your current code runs in O(n * n), you need to make it O(n). The idea is just to check in which positions there is the letter you need and use a bit of math to calculate the amount of substrings that contain that letter. You will also need to think of a strategy to avoid counting overlaps.

Comment: Yes but not getting a way to do

Comment: I have formula to calculate substring ... N(N+1)/2  but no idea how to mathematical calculate the presence of character into it

Comment: @V_for_Vj think given an index of the string, how many substrings contain that index